# Pass Column value to parameter in Dataflow task SSIS

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I have a SQL table TABLE1 which has columns ID and LastModifiedDate.Now I have one oracle query `SELECT * From Table where NEWID =?` where parameter will be the value from ID column from TABLE1 and I need to insert these records into a destination table on a SQL Server.Please advise the best approach for this.I am using SQL 2008.

Comment: Can you clarify: which tables are in Oracle and which are in SQL Server? I guess you would prefer to put your logic in SQL Server rather than Oracle and use Oracle purely as a source. Are you limited to using SSIS?

Comment: Where is 'some destination table'?. Is it in Oracle or the same SQL Server or a different SQL Server?

Comment: Source is oracle and Destination is SQL

Comment: Is it the SAME SQL Server as TABLE1? Please consider supplying all information in future. (I have edited your original question)

Answer (score 0):

Where @Id will be parameter

```
INSERT INTO DESTINATIONTABLE
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE NEWID IN(SELECT ID From Table1 WHERE ID=@ID)
```

or if you want to specify the columns you could use

```
INSERT INTO DESTINATIONTABLE(Col1,Col2)
SELECT Col1,Col2
FROM TABLE
WHERE NEWID IN(SELECT ID From Table1 WHERE ID=@ID)
```

Comment: Given that some tables are in Oracle and some are in SQL, this is of no use. Perhaps you could enhance this answer to utilise `OPENROWSET` instead.

Comment: Oops! I didn't see ORACLE. Sorry. Will update @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Here my Source is oracle which expects ID from SQL table and then insert record in SQL table